# Using Entity Field Queries with "does not contain"?

Tags: database

I have an [EFQ](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) that selects all nodes with titles not equal to 'panda'.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;

$results = $query
 ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
 -> propertyCondition('title', 'panda', '!=')
 ->execute();
```

How would I go about changing this query to give me only nodes whose titles don't contain the word 'panda' at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments on the [official documentation page for propertycondition()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3apropertyCondition/7) give an example using sql `like` on propertycondition().

From that example try the following change to your code:

```
   -> propertyCondition('title', '%panda%', 'NOT LIKE')
```

**EDIT:** I haven't actually tried this, just going offa docs and comments.

Comment: I assumed the space would cause an error because of other operators requiring underscores, but it works!

Comment: The generic code to use is `->propertyCondition('title', '%' . db_like($str) . '%', 'NOT LIKE')`. This works when you don't have a static string to look for, and the string that could contain _%_ which should be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the added information @kiamlaluno, i was just directly answering his question as-is. Do you know why the API page doesnt list LIKE or NOT LIKE as "valid" operators?

Comment: instead of asking new question which could be directed to this thread, may I ask whether 'string%' , '%string' are acceptable ?